# what is problem in my scanner.nextLine()?

Tags: java, arrays

this is my code in java (not main function).

```
    public static double[][] run(Scanner s){
      System.out.print("The number of rows non square array: "); 
      int length = s.nextInt();
      double Arr[][] = new double[length][];
      for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
          System.out.print("Input: ");      
          int length2 = i+1;
          Arr[i] = new double[length2];
          for(int j=0; j< length2; j++) {
              while(true) {
                  try {  
                      Arr[i][j] = s.nextDouble();
                      break;
                  }
                  catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                      System.out.println("That's not correct!");
                      System.out.print("Input: ");
                      s.nextLine();
                      continue;
                  }
              }
          }
        }
        
        return Arr;
    }
```

i have some errors in my code
for example)

```
The number of rows non square array: 3
Input: 1
Input: 2 3
Input: 4a 5 6
That's not correct!
Input: 7 8 9
The number of rows in the array: 3
arr[0] 1.0
arr[1] 2.0 3.0
arr[2] 7.0 8.0 9.0
```

It works correctly. but in this case

```
The number of rows non square array: 3
Input: 1
Input: 2 3
Input: 4 5 6a
That's not correct!
Input: 7 8 9
The number of rows in the array: 3
arr[0] 1.0
arr[1] 2.0 3.0
arr[2] 4.0 5.0 7.0
```

4.0 and 5.0 not deleted. i want to print arr[2] 7 8 9 in that case
what is problem??

i have to use try-catch in this code
it doesn't deleted infront of catch

Comment: The problem with the input `4 5 6a` is that you have already read the `4` and `5` input and added them to your array, before you detect the error. Instead of reading number by number, I suggest you read the whole line into a string, and then attempt to tokenize the string itself. Only add to the array if all elements could be properly parsed.

Comment: As a quick fix, reset the index `j` when there's an error.

Comment: in catch,
s.nextLine();
j--;
continue;
is this reset the index?? but some error in this line

Comment: In the catch, `j = 0;`. You want to read a whole new line and start over from the first index.

Comment: thank you for your answer!! I've solved this problem
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

> *"... i want to print arr[2] 7 8 9 in that case what is problem??*
>
> *i have to use try-catch in this code it doesn't deleted infront of catch ..."*

Use the *[Scanner#nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())*, *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))*, and *[Double#parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))* methods.

Since I'm using *nextLine*, I've added an extra call after the *length* assignment, to move the *Scanner* cursor down a line.

And, when an exception is thrown, decrement *i*.

```java
static double[][] run(Scanner s){
    System.out.print("The number of rows non square array: ");
    int length = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();
    double Arr[][] = new double[length][];
    String[] ss;
    for (int i = 0, j, n; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        ss = s.nextLine().split(" +");
        Arr[i] = new double[ss.length];
        for (j = 0, n = ss.length; j < n; j++)
            try {
                Arr[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(ss[j]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("That's not correct!");
                i--;
                break;
            }
    }
    return Arr;
}
```

Output

```
The number of rows non square array: 3
Input: 1
Input: abc
That's not correct!
Input: abc 123
That's not correct!
Input: 2 3 
Input: 4 5 6
[1.0]
[2.0, 3.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double[][] run(Scanner s) {
        System.out.print("The number of rows non square array: ");
        int length = s.nextInt();
        double Arr[][] = new double[length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            int length2 = i + 1;
            Arr[i] = new double[length2];
            for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++) {

                try {
                    Arr[i][j] = s.nextDouble();

                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("That's not correct!");
                    s.nextLine();
                    i--;
                }

            }


        }
        return Arr;
    }
```

Whenever an exception occurs on the ith index, reduce the i index by 1 and start collecting the values of the ith index from the beginning unless and until the user enters valid values -  repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. It is giving the output as per your requirement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("The number of rows non square array: ");
        int length = s.nextInt();
        double Arr[][] = new double[length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            int length2 = i + 1;
            Arr[i] = new double[length2];
            for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
                while (true) {

                    try {
                        Arr[i][j] = s.nextDouble();
                        break;
                    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                        System.out.println("That's not correct!");
                        System.out.print("Please input from the begining ");
                        j = -1;
                        s.nextLine();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        s.close();
        
    }
```

Where I am resetting the whole inner loop iteration from j = 0.